# Postgresql - Aggregate metrics over time without timestamps?

Tags: postgresql, time-series, analytics

thanks a lot for taking the time!

I am not sure I use the correct words for what I want to describe but I'll give it a try.

We want our users to perform a certain action (game) on multiple separate days, so we calculate the percentage that has done this on 1, 2 or more dates. However, what we actually want is to see if we improve this metric over time.

I have the following SQL:

```
WITH CTE_challenges AS (
SELECT 
distinct c.userid,
Count(distinct DATE(c.createdat)) AS dates
FROM 
"challenges"."game_user" as c

INNER JOIN
"challenges"."game" AS g
ON g.id = c.gameid

WHERE 
c.userid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM "public"."non_users")
AND
g.status = 'ended'
GROUP by
c.userid
)

SELECT 
        count(distinct CASE WHEN 
                    dates = 1 
                    THEN c.userid
                    ELSE NULL end) / count(distinct c.userid)::float 
AS one_date,
        count(distinct CASE WHEN 
                    dates = 2 
                    THEN c.userid
                    ELSE NULL end) / count(distinct c.userid)::float 
AS two_dates,
        count(distinct CASE WHEN 
                    dates > 2 
                    THEN c.userid
                    ELSE NULL end) / count(distinct c.userid)::float 
AS more_dates
FROM
CTE_challenges AS c
```

- CTE join is for filtering away not ended games.

This code result in:

```
One Date    Two Dates    More Dates
0.67         0.2          0.13
```

I haven't been able to find a way to instead get a list like this:

```
Date    One Date    Two Dates    More Dates
12/6    0.67         0.2          0.13
13/6    0.68         0.18         0.14
...
```

We are using Redshift so generate_series not an option. Also I was thinking about a window function but haven't been able to apply it correctly. .

Oh, and please let me know a better name or tags for the question so more people can find it!

EDIT:

Adding some info after questions. 
So we want to know the % of users that has played 1, 2 or more games for each day, not just until now. We want this because we are making changes meant to improve (higher) the % of users that has played games on separate dates. A way of phrasing it could be:

"On each date in time, which % of users have played games on '1', '2' and 'more' separate dates, up until that date".

This is our game_user table: [image]

Comment: Interesting question +1, but your expected output confuses me somewhat.  The "One Date" column represents a distinct count of all dates, not just on a single date.

Comment: can you share some sample data in the tables `challenges.game` & `challenges.game_user`? Also, please explain more clearly what you are trying to do. where are the dates expected to come from and what do they represent.

Comment: Updated the question a bit - did that help?